# Python Regex For Decimal Numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex. Need help refining it.

```
(\d{1,2}\.\d{1})
```

Please Match: 22.7, 22.
Don't Match: 222.7

[Link To Regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%7D)&test_string=Please%20Match%3A%2022.7%2C%2022.%0ADon%27t%20Match%3A%20222.7&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: What exactly is the question you're asking?

Comment: Try `\b\d{1,2}\.(?:\d\b)?`

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) As written, this is kind of "gimme teh codez" because it's unclear exactly what help you need. It's also unclear exactly what pattern you're trying to implement; for example, why are 22.7 and 22. matches? Why *isn't* 222.7 a match? Can you [edit] to describe it more completely?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for quick help.

Comment: @Everyone: Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Today is a bad day for those who post questions with tried regexes. If you post no solution at all but explain in detail your requirements, you might get fewer downvotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : This was one those situations where I found a few wrong values right before moving code to production. You sir, saved my day.

Comment: :) Really glad to hear that. Have a nice rest of the day!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

n = re.findall("\d{1,2}\.\d*", "22.7, 22.")
```

Output:

```
['22.7', '22.']
```

Special case:

```
n = re.findall("\d{1,2}\.\d*", "222.7.")
```

Output:

```
['22.7']
```

Comment: This is also matching `222.7` that is not wanted

Comment: @Toto if you want exact matches like you describe, you can either wrap the regex between `^$` which assert positions at the start and end of the line. Or better yet, you can wrap it between `\b` which ensure that there is a word boundary character that precedes and supersedes what you're trying to match. `\b\d{1,2}\.\d*\b`

Comment: You may use my suggestion in your answer, `\b\d{1,2}\.(?:\d\b)?`. The `\b` can't follow `\d*` since there will be situations when `\b` is tested after a dot.